# Get Author name by AuthorId from Page properties using JS

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-clientobject

I'm using Sharepoint 2013 JS Client Object Model to retrieve and process the list of Pages. For each page I collect information like title etc. Each page contains also AuthorId property, which I would like to use to retrieve author's name. How to do that?

Here is my sample code:

```
 var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
 var items = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Pages').getItems(new SP.CamlQuery());
 ctx.load(items);
 ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
      var listEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
      while(listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
          var page = listEnumerator.get_current();
          alert(page.get_item('Title') + ' - ' + ...);
      }
 });
```

In addition I would also like to retrieve page url.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for the the `Include` parameter of `SP.ClientContext.load`. Its not well documented by Microsoft but there are examples on the Web. On the MSDN page, there is a community addition at the end that talks a little about it (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn168903(v=office.15).aspx).

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
 var items = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Pages').getItems(new SP.CamlQuery());
 ctx.load(items, "Include(Id, Title, Author)");
 ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
      var listEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
      while(listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
          var page = listEnumerator.get_current();
          alert(page.get_item('Title') + ' - ' + page.get_item('Author'));
      }
 });
```

### EDIT

In this next sample I have added get_lookupvalue to the Author and included EncodedAbsUrl, FileDirRef, and FileRef for you to try out for the path. The one you use depends on your needs but I suspect you'll want EncodedAbsUrl or FileRef. Here is an example of what each returns:

EncodedAbsUrl: `http://yourserver.com/Pages/home.aspx`

FileDirRef: `/Pages`

FileRef: `/Pages/home.aspx`

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
 var items = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Pages').getItems(new SP.CamlQuery());
 ctx.load(items, "Include(Id, Title, Author, EncodedAbsUrl, FileDirRef, FileRef)");
 ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
      var listEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
      while(listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
          var page = listEnumerator.get_current();
          alert(page.get_item('Title') + ' - ' + page.get_item('Author').get_lookupValue() + ' - ' + page.get_item('EncodedAbsUrl') + ' - ' + page.get_item('FileDirRef') + ' - ' + page.get_item('FileRef'));
      }
 });
```

Comment: This is close but page.get_item('Author') will return an object. I'm not sure how to access author's name?
Also, how to get page url?

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I was struggling to get the Author name from the list item.  I was missing .get_lookupValue().